# put text on left side, image on the other one

Tags: html, css, web

I want to have text on the left side of the useres screen and on the right side and Image. Look at the prototype i provided![enter image description here][1]
I can't find a solution pls help

I cant upload images, but heres a link to it
https://photos.app.goo.gl/97ZLoYcLBsVsRnjc6

I tried to do it with floats. But it didnt work out, since the button would just be way to far away from the text. The Image shouldt take away any space, it should display on the right side

Comment: Please what you tried [example]

Comment: Learn how to use flex: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ . This is the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `flex` in this case

Refer CSS flex for further changes >> [CSS Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height:100vh
}

.container-button {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.container-img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-text">
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
    <h4>This is some Text</h4>
    <button class="container-button">button</button>

  </div>
  <img class="container-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100/FFFFFF/000000">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.container-right-side img{
  margin-right: 2rem;
  max-width: 60vw;
  width: 100%;
}

.container-left-side{
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 600px){
  .container{
    flex-direction: column; 
    
  }
  .container-left-side{
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-left-side">
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
    <h4>This is Some text</h4>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container-right-side">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 70px;
  background-color: black;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
/*   align-items: center; */
  width: 50%;
  padding: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.image {
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

button {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>This is Some Text</p>
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300 " alt="Image">
  </div>
</div>
```